# What security feature is this exactly?

Tags: web-application, account-security

I noticed that web apps like Gmail, Microsoft, Roundcube etc. when logging in, times out.

To be more specific - if I i.e. open up Gmail and enter the username or NOTHING AT ALL(!) and after two hours or so get back to the tab and try to login the request fails.

What kind of security does this offer at all?

Is this for the case that the user inputs their username and doesn't finish the process or what?

Comment: See [login CSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#login-csrf). The token expires after a while (servers do not have infinite resources) so you have to refresh the page to get a new one before trying to sign on.

Comment: @JohnWu It's not so much due to resource limitation, but that you don't want tokens to be alive forever. If I take an old computer, extract a cached security token from a random login in the past, it should NOT allow me to continue that session. The method of extraction is trivial, so it only makes sense for them to expire. If anything, tokens that expires will use **more** resources because the same user will keep generating new tokens, but the "more" is so trivial that it is irrelevant.

Comment: So the token is usually a JWT token which is saved in a DBMS or what exactly? Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: it sounds like they have anti-csrf on the form and it's using a different key for encrypting the anti-csrf token for each form (tied to the session).  After login they'll create a new session (to avoid session-fixation) Usually people don't bother creating a session before login or using anti-csrf there, so this is more secure.  MS and Google may have more of a need for this because of the certificates they store. (?)